# Has many relationship using elasticsearch rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, relationships

I have two models namely 'Trait' and 'RequiredNutrient'. These two models are associated with has_many relationship, i.e. trait has many_required_nitrients.

below is the model structures,

Trait(id, name, result)
RequiredNutrient(id, nutrient, logic, value)

My trait.rb is as follows,

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'
class Trait < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  mappings dynamic: false do
    indexes :name, analyzer: 'english' 
    indexes :result, analyzer: 'english' 
    indexes :required_nutrients do
      indexes :nutrient, analyzer: 'english'
      indexes :logic, analyzer: 'english'
      indexes :value, analyzer: 'english'
    end
  end

  has_many :required_nutrients

  def as_indexed_json(options = {})
    self.as_json({
    only: [:id, :name, :result],
    include: {
      required_nutrients: { only: [:id, :nutrient, :logic, :value] }
     }
    })
  end

  def self.search(result, trait_name)
  __elasticsearch__.search(
  {
     query: {
      bool: {
        must: [
          {
            match: {
              name: trait_name
             },
            match: {
              result: result
            } 
          },
        {
          nested: {
            path: "required_nutrients", 
            query: {
              bool: {
                must: [ 
                  {
                    match: {
                      "required_nutrients.nutrient" => "Carbohydrates"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }}}
  )
 end
end

Trait.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.delete index: Trait.index_name rescue nil
Trait.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.create index: Trait.index_name, body: { settings: Trait.settings.to_hash, mappings: Trait.mappings.to_hash }

Trait.import force: true
```

I want required_nutrients whose 'nutrient' value is equal to 'Carbohydrates' and whose trait name is 'abc' and trait result is 'xyz'.

I am getting below error message when I run this method:

```
nested object under path [required_nutrients] is not of nested type
```

When I try 'Trait.last.as_indexed_json' in my console, I get the following result,

```
=> {"id"=>90, "name"=>"Saturated Fat Sensitivity", "result"=>"Normal", "required_nutrients"=>[{"id"=>77, "nutrient"=>"Carbohydrates", "logic"=>"equal to", "value"=>"90", "unit"=>"gm"}]}
```

Comment: Perhaps are you doing an 'AND' search and no results actually match the query? trait_name:Saturated Fat Sensitivity AND result;'Normal' and no required_nutrients with said name and result is found.

Comment: Nope buddy! You haven't understood my question. read it carefully!

Comment: "whose 'nutrient' value is equal to 'Carbohydrates' and whose trait name is 'abc' and trait result is 'xyz'" I don't think this is any different then and AND search. ry to activate the query logging and check them against your documents: `Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true`